# Launching different kernels

Tags: 14.04

I have compiled a Real-time Patched Kernel on my Linux Box. I usually run Ubuntu 14.04.

On Debian, at bootup, one is given a list of kernels which are installed in the system. One chooses a specific kernel from this list.

How does one do the same in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has GRUB as well as debian. If it doesn't show, press and hold Shift (or maybe Esc) just after the BIOS screen. It will look like this:

[image]

Then you can choose which kernel, after selecting "Advanced option for Ubuntu".

[image]

Comment: On some UEFI machines shift does not call grub. It may be ESC or something else.

Comment: @UdayanMallik please accept if you can :) Click the tick below the down arrow!